# Liferay CSRF protection with @ResourceMapping

Tags: liferay, csrf, liferay-6, csrf-protection

I need to add CSRF token (p_auth) to my Liferay (ver.6.1.1) portal project.
Liferay provides this ability out of the box with `auth.token.check.enabled=true`

But it does this only for requests marked with @ActionMapping annotation [[source]](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/authentication-token). At that time, as I need CSRF protection for @ResourceMapping because I have a lot of ajax requests for form submitting.

Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the way for implementation of protection in http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/26782849